C# EF adds random column in query on SaveChanges()
For some reason EF adds column to insert query. That column didn't ever exist in my model, anybody has more info about this?
My model:
public partial class EvidencijaAktivnosti
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int IdAuto { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid IdAktivnosti { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid IdSkupina { get; set; }
    public string? IdKorisnika { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
    public string? Napomena { get; set; }
    public Guid IdKlub { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}


Here is DbContext of that entity
modelBuilder.Entity<EvidencijaAktivnosti>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("EvidencijaAktivnosti_pkey");

            entity.ToTable("EvidencijaAktivnosti");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("uuid_generate_v4()");
            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
                .HasColumnType("timestamp without time zone");
            entity.Property(e => e.Datum).HasColumnType("timestamp without time zone");
            entity.Property(e => e.IdAuto).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.Property(e => e.Napomena).HasMaxLength(5000);
            entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
                .HasColumnType("timestamp without time zone");
        });


Here is code that saves it:
 db.EvidencijaAktivnosti.Add(data);
 await db.SaveChangesAsync();

End lastly here is generated query (note: "AktivnostiId"):
INSERT INTO "EvidencijaAktivnosti" ("Id", "AktivnostiId", "CreatedAt", "Datum", "IdAktivnosti", "IdAuto", "IdKlub", "IdKorisnika", "IdSkupina", "Napomena", "UpdatedAt")
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10);

Ofc I get error:
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column "AktivnostiId" of relation "EvidencijaAktivnosti" does not exist
          MessageText: column "AktivnostiId" of relation "EvidencijaAktivnosti" does not exist

In DB i don't have this column, I have tried searching for "AktivnostiId" but no luck, I have tried cleaning project with no luck!

Check your DbContextModelSnapshot for this column. If you forgot to create a migration that was supposed to remove/rename this column, it might be the culprit.

EF doesn't add random columns. Your classes break EF's naming conventions but your model code doesn't specify this. As far as EF knows, there's a relation to Aktivnosti whose FK ID is, by convention that isn't contradicted by the model, AktivnostiId. Not IdAktivnosti. EvidencijaAktivnosti looks like a bridge entity and yet no relations are configured to either Evidence or Activity

EF deals with entities, not tables. If you have Evidence, Activity and EvidenceActivity entities EF will try to map them to tables using specific defaults. If you don't like them you have to specify the different tables and columns in the model.

I use DB first approach, so there is nothing in DbContextModelSnapshot. @Irwene

There is no "Evidencije" table, there is only "Aktivnosti" and "EvidencijeAktivnosti" 1-m relation. DB First added navigation object that I have deleted and is not mentioned anywhere. Other tables use same naming convetion like this one, they work with no problem.  @PanagiotisKanavos

Is there another partial class definition that includes a navigation property called "Aktivnosti"? From the exception there appears to be, and EF will be defaulting to look for a column called "ActivostiId" where you appear to have a property named "IdAktivnosti"  When you mention deleting navigation properties created by the DbFirst Scaffolding, that is a big concern. You may have removed stuff from one side of a relationship but there are other related mappings. EF is designed to use navigation properties, it is not intended to just be a substitute for ADO.

@user2836291 EF doesn't check the database for tables, it uses the metadata information specified either through conventions or explicit configuration through the fluent API. The configuration you posted covers only properties, not relations, so EF will use the naming conventions. You didn't post all the relevant classes so people have to guess what the code looks like from the resulting error

@user2836291 Other tables use same naming convetion like this one I'm not talking about table naming conventions, but relation conventions. EF doesn't care about tables, only entities. If you have a Post and Tag entities with Post.Tags and Tag.Posts properties, EF expects the PKs to be Id or PostId and TagId.  In the basic many to many mapping it expects a PostTags table
